# from Spring context to Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm moving my project package from Spring xml file configuration to class annotation configuration.
Im stuck with a bean instantiation failed on a bean defined in a another context xml file.
This is the definition :

```
<bean id="mglsChecker" class="DefaultMglsAdapter" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg value="${mgls.server.address}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${mgls.fname}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${mgls.lcount}"/>
    </bean>
```

the mglsChecker class is defined in an infrastucture package common to the entire "solution".
The issue is that the variables "${}" are not defined so now this class is not instantiated. 
I dont understand how it works when my project is xml file configured. 
In the original applicationContext.xml I dont see any references to this mglsChecker context file.
Any help where should i look into ? what am i missing ?
 thanks,

Comment: As you are moving away from XML contexts, can you provide also the relevant Java code? In particular it would be useful to understand whether you are trying to load that context file anywhere. Spring doesn't make assumptions as to the xml files you want to load so either it's loaded (manually?) or the class won't be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
@Configuration
class YourConfig {
    // you usually don't need to explicitly give the bean name
    // if you don't, Spring gives it the config's method name
    @Bean(name = "mglsChecker", destroyMethod = "close") 
    MglsAdapter mglsChecker(@Value("${mgls.server.address}") String address,
                                   @Value("${mgls.fname}") String  fname,
                                   @Value("${mgls.lcount}") long lcount) {
        return new DefaultMglsAdapter(address, fname, lcount);
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer creating `@Component` classes, but for that you need to be able to edit the `DefaultMglsAdapter` class.

```
@Component
class DefaultMglsAdapter implements MglsAdapter {
    // fields to hold the configs
    DefaultMglsAdapter(@Value("${mgls.server.address}") String address,
                                   @Value("${mgls.fname}") String  fname,
                                   @Value("${mgls.lcount}") long lcount) {
        // set fields
    }
    @PreDestroy
    void close() {
        // cleanup
    }
}
```

EDIT: incorporated Andreas' correction :)

Comment: Although this is good (+1), it's missing the `destroy-method="close"` part of the old `<bean>` definition.

Comment: @Andreas Oh, I missed that. I don't see how that could be easily done without changing the adapter class to a `@Component` class.

Comment: [`@Bean(name = "mglsChecker", destroyMethod = "close")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)

Answer (score 1):

Load the properties in the java file via

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class DefaultMglsAdapter{

    //...
}
```

Inject the properties via

```
@Value( "${mgls.server.address}" )
private String serverAddress;
```

Comment: This is missing the `destroy-method="close"` part of the old `<bean>` definition.

Answer (score 0):

The variables which are mentioned with "${}" syntax are key/place-holders of properties.
Please search or find such key from *.properties or *.config or *.xml or any such custom properties files. If you find any such properties file then specify classpath or location of that file where you want to configure it as given below:

By XML:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:path/to/PropertiesFile"/>
```

By Annotation:

```
@Configuration    
@PropertySource("classpath:path/to/PropertiesFile")    
@Value("${Property}")
```

Thanks and Regards.